# Watching/ignoring a non-existent tag results in a visual glitch

Tags: bug, ignored-tags, tag-watching

This is a pretty small visual bug, but a bug nonetheless (on any Stack Exchange site):

1. Go to the site's main page.
2. Click on "Edit" under the "Ignored Tags" or "Watched Tags" section
3. Type in random text/something that's not a tag
4. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>

The random text that's not a tag will pop up for a split second and then disappear, and the error message will appear.

I guess I would like Stack Overflow to be able to detect if the tag is actually a tag first **before** making the tag appear in the blue box.

Comment: Where is the glitch? The tag is added to the list of watched or ignored tags, and then removed because it's not actually a valid tag. I suppose you are requesting that the validation be performed *first*, before the tag is added to the list?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, I guess that's what I'm looking for. Can this ever get implemented?

Comment: I don't know. I guess we'll see, now that you've requested it.

Comment: Asked before, hard to find back.  That's what you do when creating a web app that needs to be usable with potentially seconds of latency.  You assume the 99.9% odds for success so the user doesn't start wildly clicking to get something to happen.  Feature, not a bug.